# why is height and width when declared as a constant gives the default value?

Tags: max, processing, min

When I use the `height` and `width` as a constant I was wondering why it's giving me the value 100? Is it because `size();` was not declared above? How do I set it to the size of the canvas? Because the following prints `100`

Any help would do!!

Here is a copy of my code:

```java
final int SIZE = height;

void setup() {
 size (1000,1000);
 println(SIZE); 

}
```

Comment: @thatotherguy Note that this is a Processing question, not a Java question. Processing programs have a slightly different syntax, and the code in the question actually is an MCVE in Processing. More info here: [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321127/873165)

Answer (score 3):

For primitive types the value itself is stored in a variable.
So when you call `final int SIZE = height;` `SIZE` will have the value which `height` had immediately prior to that assignment. All subsequent changes to `height` will not affect `SIZE`.

Answer (score 2):

The `width` and `height` variables are set when you call the `size()` function. You're using them outside of a function, which means they're happening **before** the `size()` function is called, which is why they still have their default values.

To fix this, you need to move the variable initialization to be after `size()` is called:

```
int SIZE;

void setup() {
 size (1000,1000);
 SIZE = height
 println(SIZE); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the processing documentation for [size()](https://processing.org/reference/size_.html):

> ... If size() is not used, the window will be given a default size of 100 x 100 pixels.

and [`height`](https://processing.org/reference/height.html):

> ... The value of height defaults to 100 if size() is not used in a program.

This means as long `size()` was not called, the values for `height` and `width` are initialized to 100.

If you read the variables before, as you do it, then they will return 100.

You have to initialize `SIZE` after calling `size()`:

```
void setup() {
    size (1000,1000);
    SIZE = height;
}
```