# I need to make the ball roll from one end to another consistently with these given constants and variables using processing

Tags: processing

```
final int X_START = 1;
final int Y_START =250 ;
final int X_END =width ;
final int Y_END =250 ; 
final int SPEED_FACTOR = 5;

int xCenter= ;
int yCenter= ;

void setup(){
    size (500, 500) ;
}

void draw(){
    background(0);
    ellipse(xCenter, yCenter, 50, 50);
}
```

the ball has to move from xstart to xend and come back and need help with the calculations please

Comment: Sounds like an interesting assignment. Which part of this are you stuck on?

Comment: First of all you have to init `X_END=width` after `size(500, 500);`. See [why is height and width when declared as a constant gives the default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614731/why-is-height-and-width-when-declared-as-a-constant-gives-the-default-value/52615570#52615570)

Comment: Put the following line into `draw()` and see what happens `xCenter += SPEED_FACTOR; if (xCenter > X_END) { xCenter = X_START; }`

Comment: @Rabbid76 , thanks it works!

Comment: size= (MAX_SIZE*mouseY)/(width); i also have another issue please,  Im trying to make an object size to be the MAX_SIZE value at the top bottom of the screen and MIN_SIZE( these are constants) value and at the top of the screen. can you help with the arithmetic please?

Answer (score 0):

First, a few notes (comments) on the code you posted:

```
final int X_START = 1;
final int Y_START =250 ;
// you should either set this to be 500 or have it as non-final, but initialized in setup()
// because width will be zero before size() gets called
final int X_END =width ;
final int Y_END =250 ; 
final int SPEED_FACTOR = 5;
// values missing here
int xCenter= ;
int yCenter= ;

void setup(){
    size (500, 500) ;
}

void draw(){
    background(0);
    ellipse(xCenter, yCenter, 50, 50);
}
```

Maybe you meant something like this ?

```
final int X_START = 1;
final int Y_START =250 ;
final int X_END =250 ;
final int Y_END =250 ; 
final int SPEED_FACTOR = 5;

int xCenter = 250;
int yCenter = 250;

void setup(){
    size (500, 500) ;
}

void draw(){
    background(0);
    ellipse(xCenter, yCenter, 50, 50);
}
```

This snippet alone doesn't illustrate your attempt at solving the problem.
There are multiple ways of achieving the same thing and "roll the ball" sounds a bit ambiguous. If your ball is the white ellipse you draw moving it from one position to another without rotating (rolling) it won't be distinguishable visually (e.g. if you're ball is "rolled" at 90 degrees it's impossible visually tell difference from the ball "rolled" at 0 degrees).

Assuming you want to move the ball from `X_START`,`Y_START` to `X_END`,`Y_END` with a speed of 5px per frame, all you need to do is increment the value of `xCenter` and `yCenter` by `SPEED_FACTOR` at each frame. To increment by an amount you simply add that amount to the existing value:

```
xCenter = xCenter + SPEED_FACTOR;
```

There's also a shorthand for writing the above.
Please do the same for `yCenter` and try it out.
Please write a comment with your updated `draw()` implementation to this answer, ideally with the shorthand version.